# Is request-reply EIP (InOut) possible with Camel and Kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-camel, spring-kafka

Is it possible to implement the request-reply enterprise integration pattern (EIP) with Camel and Kafka?
It works well with ActiveMQ but I can't get it to work with Kafka. The ProducerTemplate receives a Reply  derived from `exchange.getIn()`, before the Consumer has even received the Request.
Upon further inspection, it appears that `KafkaProducer`  doesn't implement any of the reply listening logic nor the `replyTo` headers, that are present in `JmsProducer`.

I am using `springboot-camel:3.11.0`

Here is the sample code:

**Producer test:**

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = MyApplication.class)
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ActiveProfiles("integration-test")
public class RequestReplySampleRouteIntegrationTest {
    
    @Produce private ProducerTemplate producerTemplate;


    @Test
    public void shouldSendRequestAndReceiveReply() throws Exception {
        String topic = RequestReplySampleRoute.REQUEST + "?exchangePattern=" + ExchangePattern.InOut.name();

        String results = (String) producerTemplate.requestBody(topic, "a request");

        assertThat(results, equalTo("Post processed: [a request]"));
    }

}
```

**Route in Consumer:**

```
@Component
public class RequestReplySampleRoute extends RouteBuilder {
    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RequestReplySampleRoute.class);
    
    public static final String REQUEST_QUEUE = "kafka:request-reply";
    public static final String REPLY_QUEUE = "kafka:request-reply.reply";

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        from(REQUEST)
                .process(exchange-> {
                    Message message = exchange.getMessage();
                    Object body = message.getBody();
                    message.setBody(String.format("Post Processed: [%s]", body));
                })
                .to(ExchangePattern.InOnly, REPLY_QUEUE)
        .end()
        ;

    }
}
```

**pom.xml:**

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-kafka-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<dependencyManagement>
<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.6</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
        <version>3.11.0</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Comment: So I would caution against this. Kafka was designed as an event streaming system. AMQ/Artemis is a queuing system. Kafka is not a replacement for AMQ the two are very different beasts. There are some ways to get it working in Kafka. not sure about Camel as this would be outside what Kafka was designed for.  Artemis/AMQ is very close in performance to Kafka in some cases and if you really need request/reply on a queue I have seen this work in production. The work around for Kafka might not be production ready.

Comment: See this link on this topic by Confluence: https://www.confluent.io/resources/kafka-summit-2020/synchronous-commands-over-apache-kafka/